# How to show a windows from in a SignalR callback method?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, signalr

I am working on a simple chat application that uses SignalR for its communication.
I want to show a MessageForm whenever a private message is received from another user.
The problem is , the callback method is running on a different thread and it seems that there's a problem merging the new form loop with the main form,thus the application hangs 
Here's my callback method :

```
private void MessageReceived(object sender, Client.MessageEventArgs args)
    {
        var form = new MessageForm();
        form.MessageReceived(sender,args);
        form.Show();
    }
```

So the question is how I can create the form so that it uses the main form loop ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer :)
I was a little bit confused because I was using the from.Invoke method to run the show method and obviously it didn't work because the form had been created in callback thread then I used the main from Invoke method and viola , It works like a charm :)
Here's the code :

```
private void MessageReceived(object sender, Client.MessageEventArgs args)
    {

        var form = new MessageForm();
        form.MessageReceived(sender,args);
        Invoke(new Action(form.Show));
    }
```